# Find index of sub document in array of object

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am developing a application in Node.js with use of mongodb and mongoose. I want to get the index of object from array of object returned by mongoose the data is given below, how can I get the index from details Array where record contains particular id like

> _id: 5334032ad1c4d2d616ad3a47

The actual problem is that I am rendering a page which shows data of single nested record of details record, the id of that record is contained in my url like this

> `http://localhost:3000/id-of-parent-course/id-of-nested-doc-in-details`

I am passing all the data to that page because I want to access the total count of details record, may be my way of doing this is wrong you can correct me with answer

```
course: 
   { __v: 1,
     _id: 5334032ad1c4d2d616ad3a46,
     updatedAt: Fri Mar 28 2014 13:14:07 GMT+0530 (IST),
     createdAt: Thu Mar 27 2014 16:23:30 GMT+0530 (IST),
     comments: [],
     details: 
      [ { status: 'Core',
          course_type: 'New',
          _id: 5334032ad1c4d2d616ad3a47,
          books: [Object],
          course_content: [Object],
          learning_outcomes: [Object],
          objectives: [Object],
          senate_approval_on: Fri Mar 14 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST),
          ac_approval_on: Wed Mar 19 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST),
          center_approval_on: Wed Mar 12 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST),
          focus_group_approval_on: Tue Mar 11 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST),
          effect_from: Tue Apr 01 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST),
          pre_requisite: 'Javascript',
          offered_for: 'B.Tech',
          structure: [Object],
          department: 'ICT',
          course_no: 12345,
          title: 'Course 1' },
        { status: 'Core',
          course_type: 'New',
          _id: 533528472ad1706170b502b0,
          books: [Object],
          course_content: [Object],
          learning_outcomes: [Object],
          objectives: [Object],
          senate_approval_on: Fri Mar 14 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST),
          ac_approval_on: Wed Mar 19 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST),
          center_approval_on: Wed Mar 12 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST),
          focus_group_approval_on: Tue Mar 11 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST),
          effect_from: Tue Apr 01 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST),
          pre_requisite: 'Javascript',
          offered_for: 'B.Tech',
          structure: [Object],
          department: 'ICT',
          course_no: 12345,
          title: 'Course 1' } ] } }
```

Comment: what exactly does the array index represent?

Comment: the index value in details array which contains the nested document having particular id

Comment: I'm asking why you need the index on the element of the array which has this id?

Comment: because I want to pass that index value to next page i am rendering in Nodejs

Comment: So I'm agreeing with the general statements from @AsyaKamsky here and I want to ask you to update your question with **exactly** how you intend to use this. Because I think your "paging" problem here can be fixed with "limit" and "skip" using aggregate in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to iterate over the array and keep the index, like:

```
var i=0,
    found=false;
for(i = 0; i < course.details.length; i++) {
  var detail = course.details[i];
  if(detail._id === idYouReSearchingFor) {
     found=true;
     break;
  }
}

if(found) //your index is on variable i
```